# ¿Como obtener unicamente los campos que se solicitan, sin mostrar la estructura del documento?

Tags: mongodb

### Ejemplo de estructura del documento

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4ae50fbdc1cd6351dab49f"),
    "nombre" : "usuario1",
    "Correo" : "correo1@gmail.com",
    "playlist" : 
     [ 
        {
            "nombrePlay" : "play1",
            "descPlay" : "descPlay",
            "canciones" : 
            [ 
                {
                    "nombre":"canción1",
                    "año":"07/09/2019"
                },
                {
                    "nombre":"canción2",
                    "año":"07/09/2019"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### Lo que quiero

Al momento de buscar me interesa que solo me muestre los datos que estoy solicitando y no toda la estructura del documento.

**Lo que quiero que regrese es algo similar a lo siguiente**

```
{
    "nombre":"canción1",
    "año":"07/09/2019"
}
```

**Incluso algo valido seria lo siguiente**

```
"canciones" : 
[
    {
        "nombre":"canción1",
    }
]
```

### Como lo intente

```
db.users2.find({
    "nombre": "usuario1",
    "playlist.nombrePlay": "play1",
    "playlist.canciones.nombre": "canción1"
},
{
    "playlist.canciones.nombre": "canción1"
})
```

### Resultado

Me muestra unicamente los datos que quiero, el problema es que también regresa la estructura del documento y los demás elementos de la lista **Cuando solo quiero el elemento que busco**.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4ae50fbdc1cd6351dab49f"),
    "playlist" : 
     [ 
        {

            "canciones" : 
            [ 
                {
                    "nombre":"canción1",
                    "año":"07/09/2019"
                },
                {
                    "nombre":"canción2",
                    "año":"07/09/2019"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres, vas a tener que hacerlo con el aggregation.

Mira a ver con esto si te valdría:

```
user,playlist,song='usuario1','play1','cancion1'

df = prueba.collectionP.aggregate([{'$unwind': '$playlist'},
                                   {'$match': {'nombre': user,
                                               'playlist.nombrePlay': playlist}},
                                   {'$unwind': '$playlist.canciones'},
                                   {'$match': {'playlist.canciones.nombre': song}},
                                   {'$project': {'_id': '$playlist.canciones.nombre',
                                                 'fecha': '$playlist.canciones.año'
                                                 }}
                                   ])
```

Esto te dará como resultado un cursor que recorriendolo dará lo siguiente, aunque se puede cambiar modificando la etapa $project:

```
for d in df:
    print(d)

{'_id': 'canción1', 'fecha': '07/09/2019'}
```

Por otro lado, en tu ejemplo de documento has puesto `"nombre" : "usuario1"` pero tienes `"name": "usuario1"` en el código en el que lo has intentado (imagino que será un error al haberlo pasado aquí).

Por último, he puesto como salida `fecha` en vez de `año`, ya que creo que es mejor evitar las eñes (así como las tildes de código).

Comment: sobre el `nombre` si fue un error al pasarlo estoy probando lo que colocaste como respuesta y hasta ahora funciona, are prueba con otros datos para ver como reaccióna

Comment: Ok, ya me dirás. He editado el código cambiando '$project': {'_id': '$cancion1' por '$project': {'_id': '$playlist.canciones.nombre' para que te coja el nombre de la canción que hayas elegido.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la respuesta deseada debes utilizar agregaciones, con la siguiente obtendrias el resultado deseado

```
db.tabla.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {"Correo":"correo1@gmail.com"} //busqueda
    },
    {
        $project: {rootPlay: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$playlist", 0 ] }} //Se toma el elemento 0
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot:"$rootPlay"} //se reempla la raiz por canciones
    },
    {   
        $project: {canciones:1} // Se deja solo el campo "canciones"
    }    
])
```

**Resultado**

```
{ 
    "canciones" : [
        {
            "nombre" : "canción1", 
            "año" : "07/09/2019"
        }, 
        {
            "nombre" : "canción2", 
            "año" : "07/09/2019"
        }
    ]
}
```

También podrias hacer la busqueda de forma más sencilla y luego  en código manipular el JSON para obtener los valores del array "canciones"

```
db.tabla.find({"Correo":"correo1@gmail.com"},{_id:0, "playlist.canciones": 1});
```

**Resultado**

```
{ 
    "playlist" : [
        {
            "canciones" : [
                {
                    "nombre" : "canción1", 
                    "año" : "07/09/2019"
                }, 
                {
                    "nombre" : "canción2", 
                    "año" : "07/09/2019"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Casi es lo que quiero hacer, el problema que si tengo solo una `play1` esta bien pero si tengo mas de una y quiero obtener a la mejor `play2` o alguna otra que solo las identifico por nombre como le podría hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener una más de un resultado en la playlist debes usar la siguiente

```
db.tabla.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {"Correo":"correo1@gmail.com", 'playlist.nombrePlay': {$in: ["play1", "play2"]}} //busqueda
    },
    {   
        $project: {"playlist.nombrePlay":1, "playlist.canciones":1, _id:0} // Se deja solo el campo "canciones" y el nombrePlay para identificar la lista
    }    
])
```

Resultado:

```
{ 
    "playlist" : [
        {
            "nombrePlay" : "play1", 
            "canciones" : [
                {
                    "nombre" : "canción1", 
                    "año" : "07/09/2019"
                }, 
                {
                    "nombre" : "canción2", 
                    "año" : "07/09/2019"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "nombrePlay" : "play2", 
            "canciones" : [
                {
                    "nombre" : "canción3", 
                    "año" : "07/09/2019"
                }, 
                {
                    "nombre" : "canción4", 
                    "año" : "07/09/2019"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

En este caso no se puede eliminar el root de playlist ya que es un array.